# How to add an Onclick event to an image which is inside CircleAvatar Widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a circular image inside circleAvatar on clicking which I want to open an alert dialog box.
My question is how to add clicking event inside CircleAvatar?

This is my code :

```
        Column(children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 32.0),
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 55.0,
          backgroundImage: ExactAssetImage('assets/cat.jpg'),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 20.0,
        ),
        Text('01:29:30'),
        Text(
          'Avik Kumar Mandal',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
```

Expected: onclick event on the image which is inside Circular avatar 
P.s it is a profile picture on clicking which a dialog box should appear.

Comment: I think that you must wrap the the `CircleAvatar` with another Widget

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can wrap your circular avatar with a gesture detector

```
Column(children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 32.0),
        GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
             //do what you want here
            },
            child:  CircleAvatar(
               radius: 55.0,
                backgroundImage: ExactAssetImage('assets/cat.jpg'),
            ), 
        ),
        Container(
          height: 20.0,
        ),
        Text('01:29:30'),
        Text(
          'Avik Kumar Mandal',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
```

Or

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () => print("image clicked"),
  child: AnyWidget()
),
```

Now generalize my answer.

If you want to set `OnClickListener` to some widget that  `onTap` is not implemented by default, then you should wrap the widget with `GestureDetector` or `InkWeel`

Comment: Yep onclick is working but when I am adding an alert box this is not coming up onclicking do you have any idea why this is so?

Comment: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            print('onclick');
            AlertDialog(title: Text('title'),
            content: Text('body'),
            );
        
thats hw I am using alert box

Answer (score 8):

You can use `GestureDetector` but you will lose ripple effect on image click, so a better solution would be to use `InkWell`. Wrap your `CircleAvatar` in `InkWell`

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () => print("image clicked"),
  child: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundImage: ExactAssetImage('assets/cat.jpg'),
    radius: 55,
  ),
),
```

Comment: If you have issue with how moderators handle your flags please take it to [meta].

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought someone would have already asked such question. Anyways, I've to admit that you're the only moderator having so much of free time. And we really need people like you here on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to wrap it in an IconButton, which has the benefit of a circular ripple effect.

```
IconButton(
  icon: CircleAvatar(),
  onPressed: () {},
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html), wrap your widget inside it like as,

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () => _yourMethodHere,
CircleAvatar(
          radius: 55.0,
          backgroundImage: ExactAssetImage('assets/cat.jpg'),
  ),
),
```